# Wordpress query_posts by tag doesn't work anymore(?)

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, tags

I had this code running fine forever. Some days ago it just started outputting nothing (just the `<ul></ul>`). No errors in logs:

```
<ul style="margin-left:0">
<?php query_posts('tag=pp&showposts=4'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Of course there are posts with that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem of the plugin "The Events Calendar":

*http://wordpress.org/support/topic/tags-conflict*

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `query_posts` at all.

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

Second, the `showposts` argument has long been deprecated.

Third, the `tag` argument [is not listed as deprecated,](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) [the source appears to still respect the argument](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1832), and it works when I try it. Make sure that you are using the tag slug and the name. The two may not be the same.